# Restore models in tensorflow1.0 from many steps

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp

I'd like to train my model with many epoches using Tensorflow v1.0. And my idea is to save every model in every epoch. But soon i found the current model would replace the last one.(i mean the last one would vanish.) So i want to know how to get all of the models and restore them one by one. I think it's hard and haven't got a nice solution. Thanks for every suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

`tf.Train.Saver().save()` has an argument `global_step`.
From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver):

> Savers can automatically number checkpoint filenames with a provided counter. This lets you keep multiple checkpoints at different steps while training a model.

So you should try something like:
`saver = tf.Train.Saver(...)
sess = tf.Session(...)
for epoch in num_epochs:
    ... train model...
    saver.save(sess, "MODEL_NAME", global_step=epoch)`

Note that by default, Tensorflow keeps only the last 5 checkpoints. If you want to keep them all you should initialize your `Saver` with something in the lines of:
`saver = tf.Train.Saver(max_to_keep=num_epochs)`